# Querying embeded collections MongoDB imposing conditions(AND & OR)

Tags: mongodb, conditional-operator

I am trying to query an embeded collection and achieve following condition:

`A && C || B && C || A && D || B && D`

From what i understood referring to few tutorials, the query should be something like this:

For,

case1 OR ( [case2 AND case3] OR [case4 AND case5] )

Query:

{ case1 ,[{case2,case3},{case4,case5}] }

I tried below query, but seems to be not working. please help.

```
db.hg19_refgene_47.find({ 

                "_id.c" : 1, 
            [   {
                "_id.p" : {"$gte" : 96978}, 
                "_id.ep" : {"$lte" : 103632}
                },
                {
                "_id.p" : {"$gte" : 96978}, 
                "_id.ep" : {"$lte" : 103632}
                },
                {
                "_id.p" : {"$gte" : 96978}, 
                "_id.ep" : {"$lte" : 103632}
                }
            ]   

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `$or` operator:

```
db.hg19_refgene_47.find({
  $or: [
    "_id.c" : 1,
    {
      "_id.p" : {"$gte" : 96978}, 
      "_id.ep" : {"$lte" : 103632}
    },
    {
      "_id.p" : {"$gte" : 96978}, 
      "_id.ep" : {"$lte" : 103632}
    },
    {
      "_id.p" : {"$gte" : 96978}, 
      "_id.ep" : {"$lte" : 103632}
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the OR operator which works same as SQL OR condition. One important thing to remember when you want AND condition which the subdocument always use the elemMatch Operator other wise your query will not work as expected